# "gäbe" vs. "gebe" bei indirekter Rede

Tags: difference, subjunctive, indirect-speech

Ich komme hier jedes Mal durcheinander.

Wenn ich Konjunktiv I verwende, soll das berichtend, also wertfrei sein. Konjunktiv II dagegen soll die Aussage in Zweifel ziehen. Wenn ich also keine eigene Wertung der Aussage hinzufügen möchte, muss ich dann immer *gebe* verwenden? Und sobald ich *gäbe* verwende, stelle ich die Aussage infrage?

Ich möchte zum Beispiel sagen:

> Er sagte, es gebe/gäbe eine Möglichkeit, das zu ändern.

Und ich möchte von demjenigen, mit dem ich gerade spreche, weiterführende Informationen dazu erhalten. Ich kann die übermittelte Aussage nicht überprüfen. Bedeutet das, ich muss den Konjunktiv II verwenden?

Comment: Was möchtest Du wissen? - Mir scheint, Du hast die Frage schon beantwortet: Konjunktiv I ist wertfrei, Konjunktiv II der Irrealis, also wertend. - Wäre die Überprüfung der weitergegebenen Aussage eine Wertung?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek grundsätzlich ist mir die Einteilung auch klar; ich bin nur bei der Anwendung jedes Mal auf's Neue verwirrt. Wie tohuwawohu schrieb, habe ich Hauptsatz/indirekter Rede nicht unterschieden.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hier muss man m.E. zwischen der Verwendung des Konjunktiv [**im Hauptsatz**](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Hauptsatz.html?MenuId=Word212315) und in [**indirekter Rede**](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Indirekte.html?MenuId=Word212310) trennen. Bei dem Beispiel

> Er sagte, es gebe/gäbe eine Möglichkeit, das zu ändern.

drückst Du erst einmal keine Wertung aus, sondern **berichtest in indirekter Rede** von der Aussage (und evtl. Bewertung) eines Dritten. Welche grammatische Ausprägung man hier wählt, ist m.E. eher Stilfrage. Die Variante

> Er sagte, es gäbe eine Möglichkeit, das zu ändern.

drückt für mich eher aus, dass der ursprüngliche, zitierte Sprecher die Möglichkeit in Zweifel zieht oder Hindernisse bei ihrer Verwirklichung sieht; damit würdest Du also m.E. ausdrücken, dass Du annimmst, der ursprüngliche Sprecher hätte Zweifel gehabt. Die Variante mit Konjunktiv I:

> Er sagte, es gebe eine Möglichkeit, das zu ändern.

klingt in meinen Ohren neutraler - Du referierst schlicht, was jemand anderes ausgedrückt hat. Ob der ursprüngliche Sprecher zweifelte, ist nicht klar; es ist zwar nicht ausgeschlossen, aber es gibt auch keine Indizien dafür.

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung. Da ich von "ihm" keine weiteren Informationen bekomme und zu jemand anderem sprechen muss, würde ich hier "gäbe" verwenden.

Answer (score 5):

**gebe** (Konjunktiv I) = indirekte Rede

> Er sagte, es gebe noch Kuchen.

**gäbe** (Konjunktiv II) = Möglichkeit

> Wenn es noch Kuchen gäbe, würde ich kommen.

---

**Ausnahme**

Wenn es zur Verwechslung zwischen Indikativ und Konjunktiv I kommen kann, kann anstelle des Konjunktiv I auch der Konjunktiv II verwendet werden.

Im folgenden Beispiel ist nicht klar, ob der zweite Satz noch indirekte Rede ist ('Sie sagten, sie geben eine Party.') oder eine beobachtbare Tatsache beschreibt ('Ich sehe: Sie geben eine Party.'):

> Sie sagten, es regne nicht. Sie geben eine Party.

Deshalb kann man hier die indirekte Rede durch Konjunktiv II unmissverständlich machen:

> Sie sagten, es regne nicht. Sie gäben eine Party.

Comment: Der zweite Beispielsatz bringt eine ganz andere Semantik ins Spiel, die mit dem ersten nicht korrespondiert. Er müsste etwa lauten "Es gäbe noch Kuchen, wenn Tante Rosi nicht alle Stücke aufgefuttert hätte", um zum Vergleich zu taugen.

Answer (score 1):

Die Angelegenheit klärt sich auf, wenn man in Betracht zieht, was denn die Person in direkter Rede gesagt hätte:

- Indirekte Rede: *es gebe eine Möglichkeit* ← direkte Rede: «Es gibt eine Möglichkeit.»
- Indirekte Rede: *es gäbe eine Möglichkeit* ← direkte Rede: «Es gäbe eine Möglichkeit.»

Answer (score 0):

Wertungen werden dem Konjunktiv gerne unterstellt, ergeben sich aber meist nur aus dem Kontext. Indirekte Rede ist einfach indirekte Rede - ob ich die Aussage glaube oder nicht - in indirekter Rede wird sie identisch dargestellt.

Aus direkter Rede:

> Er sagte: "Es gibt eine Möglichkeit das zu ändern"

wird in indirekter Rede

> Er sagte, es gebe eine Möglichkeit das zu ändern.

Der Berichterstatter mag das glauben, er mag darüber im Unsicheren sein, es könnte sein dass es ihm gänzlich Wurscht ist und es könnte sein, dass er keine Sekunde an eine solche Möglichkeit glaubt.

Dass das Wort "Möglichkeit" semantisch mit Zweifeln einhergeht, ist ohne Belang für die Grammatik.

> Er sagte: "Es gibt einen Weg nach Rom"

wird in indirekter Rede zu:

> Er sagte, es gebe einen Weg nach Rom.

Hier gilt das gleiche wie oben.

> Er sagte, es gäbe einen Weg nach Rom, wenn der Brenner nicht gesperrt wäre.

Der Sprecher geht hier davon aus, dass der Brenner gesperrt ist, und daraus folgt er, dass es keinen Weg nach Rom gibt. Ist der Sprecher im unklaren darüber, ob der Brenner gesperrt ist, und will nur zu Bedenken geben, dass der Weg nach Rom nicht garantiert ist, so hieße es:

> Er sagte, es gäbe einen Weg nach Rom, wenn der Brenner nicht gesperrt ist.

Je nach dem - mal gibt es einen Weg, mal gibt es keinen.

Der Sprecher kann aber auch davon ausgehen, dass der Weg nicht gesperrt ist - dann wieder mit *gebe*:

> Er sagte, es gebe einen Weg nach Rom, weil der Brenner nicht gesperrt ist.